# Can I Breed Non-Galarian Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I wanted to breed for a High IV / Good Nature Shiny Farfetch'd (Yes I know, odd choice but I have my reasons), but when the first egg hatched a Galarian one came out, even though I used a normal one.

So is it possible to breed non-Galarian forms of Pokemon in Sword and Shield? Or do I have to import them from other games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this](https://gameranx.com/features/id/192317/article/pokemon-sword-shield-how-to-breed-alolan-regular-form-pokemon-transfer-breeding-guide/) guide, which I verified and confirmed, giving a Kantonian Farfetch'd an [Everstone](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Everstone) will allow breeding to maintain its regional form.

However, this will not work for Pokemon where the base evolution, such as Pikachu and Koffing, do not have a regional form. When evolved, their evolution would be the regional variant that is found in Galar region (Standard Raichu and Galarian Weezing respectively).

Another thing to consider that the guide says:

> If a female Pokémon or Ditto holding an Everstone breeds, they will always retain their original form.

Comment: Should probably clarify that "regional evolutions" specifically refers to cases where the pre-evolution does *not* have a regional variant. You can use an Everstone to breed an Alolan Vulpix and evolve it into an Alolan Ninetales just fine, for instance.